# Unable to access Admin Page on Nodebb after linking local plugin and db on windows machine

Tags: mongodb, plugins, redis, localhost, nodebb

I installed nodebb and redis db on my windows machines and trying to link local plugin and activating through admin panel on NodeBB. I linked with the local plugin but unable to access the admin page. On command prompt its showing nodebb and redis both are connected and working fine, but when I check on browser by putting localhost:4567, it deny my access to the admin page and just showing the other users and categories.

I also gave a try with the mongodb and then tried to link with the plugin, however, I am able to see my data in mongodb, but unable to see admin page on nodebb.

Please suggest if there is any way to troubleshoot this and get access of admin in nodebb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about removing the plugin from the installation? Try running `npm uninstall plugin-name` in the root NodeBB folder and restart it.